# Is ecstasy more dangerous than cigarettes?

Tags: medical-science

I've heard a professor say it was the other way around. Can I believe it?

I've also heard that when asked, DEA didn't deny that ecstasy is safer than alcohol.

NB: I know the question is vague. However, the justification that government use to ban ecstasy is that it's dangerous. And yes it's hard to quantify.

Perhaps a good way to quantify is to use number of life years lost under "typical" usage.

Comment: I think this will largely depend on metrics and the interpretation.

Comment: When was the last time you heard of someone dieing from smoking a single cigarette?

Comment: When was the last time you heard of someone dying from a single dose of (pure, uncut by anything else) ecstasy?

Comment: @Chad: Try eating the cigarette! :) This question is a Godzilla-vs.-Frankenstein or Shark-vs.-Bear, who is more powerful question, and therefore eligible for closing. It can't be answered. How many ecstasy-pills do you compare to how many cigarettes? Do you compare average user profiles of regular users? Do you count the plain number of people, dying each year? The question is open to debate in too many directions.

Comment: Flagged as not constructive.

Comment: "I've also heard that when asked, DEA didn't deny that ecstasy is safer than alcohol." Not denying something is not the same as saying one thing is safer than the other or that they equally bad for you. It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @mmr - When was the last time someone sold pure uncut X on the street?  Maybe a better question is when will it be?  I think that the criminalization of drugs in the US is a problem of its own.  But that does not mean that the use of drugs is safe.

Comment: Okay it's VAGUE. However, most people don't think it's vague. It's notable. And it's used to curb our right. So it's a good question. With good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very hard to be objective on such claims due to:

- it is hard to quantify 'danger to health'
- objectivity of research (or lack of, due to funding that favors certain results by certain groups)

If you examine wikipedia's article on [MDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDMA#After-effects) (ecstasy) you will find this image that comes from The Lancet, a weekly peer-reviewed medical journal:

[image: Physical harm vs Dependence graph]

The original paper from which the image is taken is: [Development of a rational scale to assess the harm of drugs of potential misuse.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17382831)

It supports the claim that MDMA is less dangerous (with much lower dependence and slightly lower physical harm).

However, do not generalize, you should examine the test in details, for example:
- does test take into account problems with purity (uncontrolled substances can be mixed with scary [things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para-Methoxyamphetamine#Dangers))
- does it measure problems with dosage (very high, difference can be two *orders of magnitude*, which easily leads to accidental overdose)
- how were long term effects taken into account
- comparability of data quality

Finally, the danger is also subjective, here is a quote

> It found that the likelihood of a newspaper reporting a death from paracetamol (unclassified) was one in 250 deaths. For diazepam (Class C), it was one in 50. For amphetamine (Class B), it was one in three.
>
> For ecstasy (Class A), every associated death was reported. And I very rarely read reports in the national press about those deaths from horse-riding accidents.

I recommend reading the whole [article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/thereporters/markeaston/2009/02/equivalence_in_death.html).

Comment: Several of the problems you listed are used by the pro-legalisation lobbies. If legalised, purity, source and dose can be controlled. It would be good to add in some clarity of long term dangers versus short term.

Comment: Also -- **Wikipedia is not a reliable source here**. Please use reliable sources.

Comment: @Sklivvz, with all due respect, I would agree with you if I claimed that it is one way or another. I have emphasized that subjectivity plays a role and that presented material is inconclusive and needs further examination. I am pretty new here so pardon me if I am still making false assumptions, but reading http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-wikipedia-a-valid-reference suggest that your rule is overly generalized. Anyway, I named the magazine from which the image came, is that good enough?

Comment: @Unreason with all due respect -- no it's not enough. I cannot verify that it's true, nor that the _data_ represented it's valid (I can't access the lancet). However, the graph makes a number of surprising statements, like that cannabis and LSD induce dependence or that GHB is less harmful than cannabis, whereas it's well known that cannabis is non-lethal (no LD50) but GHB is (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-Hydroxybutyric_acid)

Comment: @Sklivvz: I added the reference to the original paper, which is open access.

Comment: @Unreason, I've read the paper and I would take the findings with **a lot** of salt -- while they say in the discussion "We believe that a system of classification like ours, based on the scoring of harms by experts, on the basis of scientific evidence, has much to commend it.", I do disagree. In fact, they only asked experts their opinion. Not a good way to avoid bias. Furthermore, they include in "harm" things like social harm and how pleasurable the drug is in "dependence". Frankly it's a *crap* study.

Comment: @Sklivvz, I see your point. Though two things still bother me from our exchange: 1) *as I said in the answer this question will have an inherent issue of objectivity* (potentially biased reasearch) 2) should I infer that wikipedia is not good for answers, but ok in the comments? (your link to GHB)

Comment: @Unreason 1) I don't get it: "My sources are not good but I will still give you my opinion" is clearly contrary to our "citation needed" policy 2) Wikipedia is fine as a general reference for well-known, undisputed facts. I've included a link to the GHB page for your convenience.

Comment: I think the answer is very good. Yes there could always be uncertainty. there could be bias and stuff. But it does look like cigaretes and alcohol are more dangerous than ecstasy.

Comment: @Sklivvz, Ok, thank you for your input, I'll try to provide better references in future. (FYI, the wiki article on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-Hydroxybutyric_acid#Reported_deaths provides a reference to http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/shared/bsp/hi/pdfs/31_07_06_drugsreport.pdf which shine some light on just how subjective the whole subject is)